# $n$ permutations in $S_n$, no two of which agree on any point

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, derangements

Q: How many tuples of permutations ($\sigma_1$,..$\sigma_n$), $\sigma_i \in S_n$ have the property that no two of them agree on any element?

This is sort of a generalization of derangements, but I feel like there should be a way to think about the problem which is not just "derangements, but more complictated." Some intuition for this is that $n$ permutations in $S_n$ is an extremal condition for this property.

I see that this is equivalent to the number of Sudoku puzzles without the subsquare conditions. I couldn't find more about this in the literature.

I would also be happy with a asymptotic solution, like derangements.

Comment: the sudoku analogy is perfect

Comment: consider that you have a $n \times n$ sudoku grid, and you fill it in such a way that every row is a permutation of the given set, and every element occurs once in a column. Then, to add a $n+1$ th row, at least 1 column will have an element repeated twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tuple of $n$ permutations, no two of which agree at any place, is exactly a [Latin Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Letting $L_n$ be the number of Latin squares, there is no formula for $L_n$. We know the following inequalities:
$$
\frac{(n!)^{2n}}{n^{n^2}}\le L_n\le \prod_{k=1}^n (k!)^{n/k}.
$$
The ratio between these two bounds grows like $n^{n/2}$, so is somewhat loose. At least we can approximate $\log L_n$ reasonably well:
$$
\log L_n= n^2\log n -2n^2 + O(n\log n).
$$